# Accessing boolean var as array in PHP return NULL

Tags: php, arrays, boolean

discussing with a friend of my work, we discover something weird about PHP. Let's get the following code:

```
<?php

$leo = false;
$retorno = $leo[0];
var_dump($retorno);
```

The return of `var_dump()` is `NULL`. Now, the thing is, why is returning NULL, if we are trying to access a `bool` as `array`?

The correct behavior isn't throw an exception telling us, that we are trying to access a non-array object as array (in this case a boolean var)?

what you guys think about that?

Comment: Until PHP 5.4, if you tried to get a string index of a string, it would cast the string to 0 and get the first letter of the word, i.e. `$s = 'asdf'; echo $s['f'];`. Now it will give you a warning saying that the offset does not exist.

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to access not a string, but a boolean it returns `NULL`. As from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

> **Note:**
>   Accessing variables of **other types** (not including arrays or objects implementing the appropriate interfaces) using [] or {} **silently returns NULL.**

Answer (score 0):

It's `NULL` because `$leo[0]` isn't `$leo`. You haven't assigned the `bool` or `string` to `$leo[0]`, therefore it's empty, and ultimately results in being `NULL`.

If you were to put:

```
$retorno = $leo;
```

Or

```
$leo[0] = false;
```

Then you would get the result you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$leo = false;
$retorno = array($leo);
var_dump($retorno[0]);
```

Try this